# Change individual column widths when using DataTables jQuery plugin

Tags: css, datatables

I am using datatables from [here](http://datatables.net). I have made a table from my database. I want to change width of each column in terms of percentage. Any relative code or example can help me?

```
<table id="example" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="60%">Name</th>
            <th width="40%">Position</th>
        </tr>
    </thead> 
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="60%">ABC</td>
            <td width="40%">DEF</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="60%">XYZ</td>
            <td width="40%">ZYX</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: try look in their documentation: http://datatables.net/manual/styling/

Comment: updated my code now @JimiLoe that link i tried and didnt help Akul

Comment: Have a look at this as well. https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.width.

Comment: Do you mean **Table** ? Because database is handled by SQL. There's no css involved !

Comment: @stevenw00 that works in IE and Firefox but not in chrome

Answer (score 1):

According to their [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.width) you can do the following:

```js
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "columns": [
    { "width": "60%" },
    { "width": "40%" },
  ]
});
```